# C++ std::shared_ptr, is operator= overloaded to use copy constructor?

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr

If I do the following:

```
class Foo
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;
    Foo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar)
    {
        this->bar = bar;
    }
}
```

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> func()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar_ptr(new Bar());
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr(new Foo(bar_ptr));
    return foo_ptr;
}
```

Will `foo_ptr` in `func()` have a valid pointer in its member variable bar? It seems that it only would if when setting `this->bar = bar` that the constructor parameter gets copied. Is the = operator for `std::shared_ptr` overridden to call the copy constructor always?

Comment: You're copying the pointer, not what it points to.

Comment: I would assume that the copy constructor for a shared_ptr does not copy what the pointer points to. But my concern here is that both `this-> bar` and `bar` in the constructor of Foo are the same reference meaning that there is really only one shared_ptr object in memory, but I have 2 variables referencing that shared_ptr.

Comment: @AlexMussell your code is ok. There is one object referenced by multiple shared_ptr. You can use use_count to explore what is going on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count

Comment: @Shawn Stop answering in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the copy constructor and the assignment operator will make the receiver share ownership with the one you pass in. However they perform that internally internally is an implementation detail.

Of course, if `this->bar` was managing something, then it would release its shared ownership of it (and if it is the last one owning it, whatever `Bar` was there will get deleted).

> But my concern here is that both this-> bar and bar in the constructor of Foo are the same reference meaning that there is really only one shared_ptr object in memory, but I have 2 variables referencing that shared_ptr.

They are not references, `bar` and `this->bar` are two different `std::shared_ptr` objects that, after the assignment, will point (internally) to the same place in memory (but they are still two different objects). However, `std::shared_ptr` is a class that knows how many other `std::shared_ptr`s are pointing to it (*shared ownership*) and will properly delete the object only once all of the others are gone (so only the last `std::shared_ptr` will destroy it).

Answer (score 1):

Here `this->bar` hold a strong reference to whatever `bar` manages:

```
Foo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar)
    {
        this->bar = bar;
    }
```

There is no copy going on here, you are just incrementing the reference count of `shared_ptr` by assigning `bar` to the member.

And yes the pointer you have as member is valid, as the lifetime is managed by the `shared_ptr`.